# Is both $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ same element $?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $P(S)$ denotes the power set of set $S$. Which of the following is always true$?$

1. $P(P(S)) = P(S)$
2. $P(S) ∩ P(P(S)) = \{ Ø \}$
3. $P(S) ∩ S = P(S)$
4. $S ∉ P(S)$

---

I try to explain $:$
If $S$ is the set $\{x, y, z \},$ then the subsets of S are:

${}$ (also denoted $\phi,$ the empty set)
$\{x\},
\{y\},
\{z\},
\{x, y \},
\{x, z \},
\{y, z \},
\{x, y, z \}$
and hence the power set of S is i.e.,

$P(S) =$ $\{\{\}, \{x\}, \{y\}, \{z\}, \{x, y\}, \{x, z\}, \{y, z\}, \{x, y, z\}\}$.

Similarly ,

$P(P(S))=\{\{\{\}\}, \{\{x\}\}, \{\{y\}\}, \{\{z\}\}, \{\{x, y\}\}, \{\{x, z\}\}, \{\{y, z\}\}, \{\{x, y, z\}\}\}.....\}$

therefore ,

$P(S) ∩ P(P(S)) = \{ Ø \}$

Note that $\{ Ø \}$ is always element of powerset of a set , and also $\{ Ø \}$ is the subset of a set , in other words all subset of a set is a powerset .

---

> My question is $:$  both $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ same element ?

Comment: You question has the same answer as the following question: Is an empty bag inside an empty bag the same thing as an empty bag?

Comment: Are your statement 3 and 4 supposed to be the same?

Comment: thanks to point out ,corrected.

Comment: I would try to explain with a smaller starting set. If $S$ has $3$ elements, then $\mathcal P(S)$ will have $2^3=8$ elements, and $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(S))$ will have $2^8=256$ elements!

Comment: The empty set is *not* denoted $\phi$, $\Phi$, ø or Ø. It is denoted $\emptyset$, $\varnothing$ or $\{\}$. The first two are \emptyset and \varnothing in TeX, respectively.

Comment: Maybe more obvious as $Ø\ne\{Ø\}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ are not the same. Think of sets as bags. $\{\}$ is an empty bag. $\{\{\}\}$ is a bag with an empty bag within it. Therefore the outermost bag is not empty: It has a bag inside it.

---

For the original question, you are wrong, lets consider all four possibilities.

1. No. By Cantor's theorem, we always have $|P(P(S))| > |P(S)|$. Hence they cannot be equal. Alternatively, let $S=\{\}$ and write out.
2. Consider $S=\{\{\}\}$. Then $P( S)=\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$ and $P(P(S))=\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}  \}$, hence $P(S) \cap P(P(S)) = \{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$.
3. No. Note that $A \cap B \subseteq B$ for all sets $A,B$. Hence  $S \cap P(S) \subseteq S$, hence $$|S \cap P(S)| \leq |S| < |P(S)|$$

   hence they are not equal.
4. By definition $S \subseteq S$ and thus $S \in P(S)$.

Therefore, none of the statements is true.

Comment: wow , nice , if we have non-empty set , then what is answer ?

Comment: @Silence For what statement?

Comment: for statement 2.

Comment: @Silence $S$ is nonempty, because it contains the empty set. Read the first paragraph again. Alternatively, $S=\{\{\},\mathrm{apple}\}$ will also work, so will any set $S$ that contains the empty set.

Comment: means 2 statement is always false ?

Comment: You are right sir , thank you.

Comment: @Silence statement 2 is false for any set that contains a set. It is not false for $S=\{1\}$ for example, since $P(S)=\{\{\},\{1\}\}$ and  $P(P(S))=\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{1\}\},\{\{\},\{1\}\}\}$.

Comment: @wythagoras In ZF(C) the elements of sets are always sets, so 2 being false for "any set that contains a set" seems a little strange.

Comment: @Christoph Is 1 a set?

Comment: Sure, usually it is defined as $1=\{0\}$ where $0=\varnothing$. There are different models of the positive integers in ZF though.

Comment: @Christoph is -1 a set? Is $\mathrm{apple}$ a set?

Comment: Again, if you take ZF(C) as the foundation you are doing mathematics with. *Every object* is a set. Usually you construct $\mathbb Z$ as a quotient of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ with respect to the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim(c,d) \Leftrightarrow a+d=c+b$, and then $-1$ is the equivalence class $\{(a+1,a)\mid a\in\mathbb N\}$, a set.

Answer (score 5):

No, $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ are two different sets. You can see that by noting that there's something that is an element of one but not of the other:

$$ \{\}\notin \{\} \qquad\text{but}\qquad \{\}\in\{\{\}\} $$

$\{\}$ is a set that *has no elements*. It is the same set that is also notated $\varnothing$.

$\{\{\}\}$ is a set which has exactly one element, namely $\{\}$. Since $\{\}$ is the same as $\varnothing$, a different name for $\{\{\}\}$ would be $\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: hah, user46944 beat you by like 8 seconds :). Obviously it's not about the time but it's the first time I've actually witnessed a question shootout :P.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: 28 seconds - and I noticed, but I decided to submit anyway such as to stress the point that _the way_ for two sets to be different is if there's something that's an element of one but not of the other -- and in this case we can easily find such a something.

Comment: I see, that's a good point. That does seem like an important distinction to make, because it could help when they hit a similar question in the future.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sir , thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

No, $\{\}$ is the empty set, and $\{ \{ \} \}$ is the set *containing* the empty set.  They aren't the same -- $\{\}$ has **no elements**, and $\{ \{ \} \}$ has **one element**.

By the way, in $P(P(S))$, you forgot to add the element $\{ \}$, since the empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: Thanks for point out my mistake .